# Sequence points in C / function calls

Tags: c

I'm just learning some C, or rather, getting a sense of some of the arcane details. And I was using VTC advanced C programming in which I found that the sequence points are :

- Semicolon
- Comma
- Logical OR / AND
- Ternary operator
- Function calls (Any expression used as an argument to a function call is finalized the call is made)

are all these correct ?. Regarding the last one I tried:

```
void foo (int bar) { printf("I received %d\n", bar); }

int main(void) 
{

  int i = 0;

  foo(i++);

  return 0;

}
```

And it didnt print 1, which according to what the VTC's guy said and if I undertood correctly, it should, right ?. Also, are these parens in the function call the same as the grouping parens ? (I mean, their precedence). Maybe it is because parens have higher precedence than ++ but I've also tried foo((i++)); and got the same result. Only doing foo(i = i + 1); yielded 1.

Thank you in advance. Please consider that I'm from South America so if I wasnt clear or nothing makes sense please, oh please, tell me.

Warmest regards, 
            Sebastian.

Comment: Compile with debugging information and all warnings (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g` on Linux or perhaps Mac) and learn to use the debugger (`gdb`)

Comment: It's hard to understand why you think it should print 1 when the value of `i++` is 0. "Only doing foo(i = i + 1); yielded 1" -- because the value of `i = i + 1`, which is equivalent to `++i`, is 1.

Comment: I know the value of i==, but I think that function calls arent really a sequence point like, for example, comma is because
foo((i++,i)) is indeed 1. And yes, I know the comma gives the last value but anyway. I got confused by the fact that "Any expression is evaluated before" isnt quite the case, even if postfix is like a 2 step operation if some one says "ALL operations" .. well .. I though it literally meant ALL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sequence means `i++` is evaluted before `foo` is invoked.

Consider this case (***I am not printing `bar`!***):

```
int i = 0;
void foo (int bar) { printf("i = %d\n", i); }
int main(void){
    foo(i++);
    return 0;
}
```

`i = 1` must be printed.

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea to print `bar` as well to avoid reader confusion…

Comment: @Potatoswatter But printing `bar` will lose the focus. I think I should said ***"I am not printing `bar`"***.

Comment: Yeah, works for me. Sorry for the temporary downvote before, I'm getting sloppy reading.

Comment: -1 this doesn't explain the problem in OP code. If you would print `bar` you would still get 0. See @Joey's answer.

Comment: But it is the beauty of it. Not only answered my question but taught me something new by introducing that global, if he wouldnt do it I was going to think that it should print i = 0 but no because when I use the variable for that second time all steps are really completed (not with bar because bar isnt really i).

Answer (score 10):

Your code is working like it should and it has nothing to do with sequence points. The point is that the postfix `++` operator *returns the non-incremented value* (but increments the variable by 1 nonetheless).

Basically:

- `i++` – Increment `i` by one and return the previous value
- `++i` – Increment `i` by one and return the value after the increment

The position of the operator gives a slight hint for its semantics.

Comment: Hi !, that was fast !! ..

Yes, I knew about postfix and prefix ++ and --.

But I got confused by what the VTC's guy said (about all operations being finished when you reach and sequence ponts and, of course, function calls being one of them).

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3):

C implements pass-by-value semantics. First `i ++` is evaluated, and the value is kept, then `i` is modified (this may happen any time between the evaluation and the next sequence point), then the function is entered with the backup value as the argument.

The value passed into a function is always the same as the one you would see if using the argument expression in any other way. Other behavior would be fairly surprising, and make it difficult to refactor common subexpressions into functions.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just new to the site. Found that I cant "green" all answers. They were all really useful, seriously, again, thank you.

Comment: @SJPRO *"green"*. The formal verb is "accept". BTW, you let me remember a Chinese poem: 春風又綠江南岸

Comment: formal or correct ? if the former, I could argue that I wasnt trying to be formal haha. And I accepted ALL of them bur I could only "green" one = ). What's that chinese stuff?, please , I dont want to google it ..

Comment: Today, unacceptable winter breeze only .. = ( .. yeah, I googled it (it was killing me)

Comment: @SJPRO I mentioned 春風又綠江南岸 just because 綠 is ordinarily a noun or an adjective, but the poet use it as a verb, just as you. Moreover, 綠 = green.

Comment: Yeap, that happens when someone is still reading and typing code at 5am, it becomes a poet.
I should try to finish this or .. well .. sleep.

See ya; !

Answer (score 1):

When you do something like:
int i = 0, j;

j = i++;

the value of i is used first and then incremented. hence in your case the values of i which is 0 is used (hence passed to your function foo) and then incremented. the incremented values of i (now 1) will be available only for main as it is its local variable.

If you want to print 1 the do call foo this way:

foo(++i);

this will print 1. Rest you know, why!